# Почему деструктор объекта в векторе срабатывает дважды?

Tags: c++, вектор, деструктор

Собственно, вопрос задан в названии темы... Вот код:

```
#include "vpx/vp8cx.h"
#include "colorspaces.h"
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef unsigned char byte;

struct video_frame{
    vpx_image_t image;
    unsigned int pts;
    video_frame(byte * BGR_buffer, unsigned int width, unsigned int height){
        pts = 0;
        if( vpx_img_alloc(&image, VPX_IMG_FMT_I420, width, height, 1)){
            colorspaces::BGRtoI420(width, height, BGR_buffer, image.planes[0], image.planes[1], image.planes[2]);
        }
        printf("Constructor OK!\n");
    }
    ~video_frame(){
        vpx_img_free(&image);
        printf("~Destructor OK!\n");
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int w = 640;
    int h = 480;
    byte * data = new byte[w*h*3]();

    // video_frame v(data, w, h); так деструктор срабатывает 1 раз

    // так деструктор срабатывает 2 раза - почему?
    std::vector<video_frame> framestack;
    framestack.push_back(video_frame(data, w, h));
    framestack.erase(framestack.begin());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: В общем случае деструктор и конструктор копирования может вызываться сколько угодно много раз, после того, как объект стал находится в векторе. Делать какие-либо предположения после этого не стоит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вашего объекта есть автоматически сгенерированный конструктор копирования, который вызывается при вызове `framestack.push_back(video_frame(data, w, h));`. Соответственно деструктор будет вызвать сначала для временного объекта а затем для объекта, сохраннего в векторе. При этом `vpx_img_free(&image);` второй раз будет вызвано для одного и того же `image` вызывая неопределенное поведение. Чтобы исправить запретите конструктор копирования и создайте конструктор перемещения (и соответствующие операторы). Кроме того, вместо `push_back` следует всегда использовать `emplace_back`.

Comment: Спасибо. А в чём преимущество `emplace_back` перед `push_back`?

Comment: @Iceman `emplace_back` позволяет избежать создания лишних временных объектов. `framestack.emplace_back(data, w, h);` получается и короче, и производительнее.

Comment: Отлично! Благодарю! Тогда получается и не нужно с конструкторами заморачиваться - декструктор один раз сработал

Comment: @Iceman Нет, с конструкторами и операторами следует заморачиваться всегда. Конструктор копирования / перемещения будет вызываться при переаллокации и удалении элементов вектора.